# How can I create conditional statements in a pipeline from values in a terraform file?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, azure-pipelines

I’m using Azure Pipelines to deploy infrastructure via terraform, and want to add a conditional statement before deployment that the tf file is not using a certain module for networking

How would I go about getting values out of the tf file and into Azure devops pipeline for use as a conditional to prevent the pipeline from running?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Do you have any TF code to show demonstrating your issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you parse the terraform output value in a string using jq or some other means then you can set a variable using Azure Devops logging command on shell and then use the value in subsequent steps and conditions using macro syntax e.g $(tfVariable). If you want to use the value in subsequent job or step, then you will need to mark the variable as output when setting it.

ref: Setting Variables: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#setvariable-initialize-or-modify-the-value-of-a-variable

ref: Using Dependencies: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#dependencies